# Find the number of ways a sequence can be rearranged

Tags: python, permutation, combinatorics

How can I find the number of ways a sequence of numbers (may contain similar items) could be rearranged so that a number is not placed in the same place as it or its similar numbers were placed.

For example, `[0,0,0,1,1,1]` could be rearranged in only one way and that is `[1,1,1,0,0,0]`.

`[0,0,0,1,1,1,1]` cannot be arranged in any way.

`[1,2,2,14]` can be arranged in 2 ways i.e `[2,1,14,2], [2,14,1,2]`.

`[1,1,2,2,14]` can be arranged in 4 ways i.e `[14,2,1,1,2], [2,2,14,1,1], [2,2,1,14,1], [2,14,1,1,2]`.

The math solution is available but I was thinking some easy way out using the programming concepts. Math code is is a little like this.. (Excuse me i could not post in the correct format)

```
∫∞0 Ln1(x)..Lnr(x)e−xdx
```

where r is the number of items, ni is the number of occurrences of item i and Lk is the k-th Laguerre polynomial. For instance, for 1,1,2,2,14, we have r=3, n1=2, n2=2, n3=1, so up to a sign the number of rearrangements is

```
∫∞0 L2(x)L2(x)L1(x)e−xdx 
= ∫∞0 12(x2−4x+2)12(x2−4x+2)(1−x)e−xdx 
= ∫∞0(−14x5+94x4−7x3+9x2−5x+1)e−xdx
= −4
```

But I was thinking if there are any python libraries which could generate all permutations as desired by us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute-force using `itertools`:

```
import itertools
def arrangements(arr):
    p = itertools.permutations(arr)
    return set(item for item in p if all(x!=y for x,y in zip(item,arr)))
```

Result:

```
>>> arrangements([0,0,0,1,1,1])
{(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)}
>>> arrangements([0,0,0,1,1,1,1])
set()
>>> arrangements([1,2,2,14])
{(2, 14, 1, 2), (2, 1, 14, 2)}
>>> arrangements([1,1,2,2,14])
{(2, 14, 1, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1, 14, 1), (14, 2, 1, 1, 2), (2, 2, 14, 1, 1)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit.. And the answer Short Simple and Sweet :) I am Using this one :) As i Had to output the no. of ways I used the len() function before set and it gave the integer as output..

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried itertools.permutations?

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

```
import itertools

def my_combos(val):
    results = []
    l = itertools.permutations(val, len(val))
    for c in l:
        if all([x != y for (x,y) in zip(c,val)]):
            results.append(c)
    return list(set(results))


print my_combos([0,0,0,1,1,1])
print my_combos([1,1,2,2,14])
```

Yields:

```
[(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)]
[(2, 14, 1, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1, 14, 1), (14, 2, 1, 1, 2), (2, 2, 14, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: Hey thnx.. for enlightening about the "itertools" :)

Answer (score 3):

More involved, but should be quite a bit faster on long input sequences:

```
from collections import Counter

def _rearrange(orig, rem):
    if len(orig)==1:
        v = rem[0][0]
        if v != orig[0]:
            yield [v]
    else:
        o, orig = orig[0], orig[1:]
        for i,(v,c) in enumerate(rem):
            if v != o:
                for r in _rearrange(orig, rem[:i]+([(v,c-1)] if c>1 else [])+rem[i+1:]):
                    yield [v]+r

def rearrange(orig):
    if len(orig) > 1:
        return list(_rearrange(orig, Counter(orig).items()))
    else:
        return []

def main():
    print rearrange([0,0,0,1,1,1])
    print rearrange([1,1,2,2,14])

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

results in

```
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
[[2, 2, 1, 14, 1], [2, 2, 14, 1, 1], [2, 14, 1, 1, 2], [14, 2, 1, 1, 2]]
```

.

**Edit:** Comparing the functions' runtimes, I get:

[image]

(blue for Tim's, green for mine; dots are data, lines are best fit (least-squares on log of data); x axis is sequence length, y axis is runtime in seconds (log scale). Data points are best of ten runs on each of twenty random sequences for each sequence length.)

Conclusions:

- Tim's fn's runtime grows as 7.44 * * n; mine grows as 3.69 * * n.
- On a ten-item sequence, his fn averages 53.9s vs 0.93s for mine; the difference slightly more than doubles for each extra item in the sequence.
- His fn has a much more consistent runtime; mine is highly variable, depending on the number of repeated items in the sequence.
- Straight-line fit does not look like the best predictor; runtimes should be a function of n!, not k * * n. I am not sure how to model this, though. Suggestions?

Comment: @FirstRock: You express your thanks best by upvoting all good answers, and accepting the best one, instead of literally thanking. Please read the FAQ about the voting system. Thanks, and welcome.

Comment: Task Complete:) Actually that time didnt have the required priveleges to do so.